# Execute stuff on multiple browser instances simultaneously

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

So I want to do stuff in my `onPrepare`. What I've done so far is fork the driver instance 2 times so I have 3 different browser windows to work with.

However, they do not execute stuff simultaneously, but waits for each other to finish. How can I make each browser do stuff independently of the other browsers?

Comment: Are you talking about three different browsers (firefox, chrome, internet explorer) or three instances of the same browser (firefox x3)? for different browsers lookup protractors multi-capabilities

Comment: Three instances of the same browser.

Comment: How you imagine that to happen? Instance 1,2,3 starts in parallel the very first test, then what? They wait for each other to complete the test and then together start the next test. Or you just have one test in your suite?

Comment: It's in my onPrepare. I want them to run independently until they're done with whatever thet do.

Comment: What happens if you set `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true` for every instance? WIll they wait for each other then as well?

Comment: You may need to look into Selenium Grid for this.